# Issue with SUM with two LEFT JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

In the query below I have trouble when I have two left joins. What happens is the sums are incorrect (elevated) with both left joins. When I remove the second left join, the query runs correctly. How can I run this query with the second left join?

```
SELECT o.IdNoLocation,
COUNT(DISTINCT o.EncodedId) AS "Frequency", 
ISNULL(SUM(o.Subtotal), 0) AS "Spend", 
ISNULL(SUM(os.Amount), 0) AS "Surcharges",
ISNULL(SUM(od.Amount), 0) AS "Discounts" 
FROM ((tblOrder o
LEFT JOIN tblOrderSurcharge os ON o.OrderId=os.OrderId) 
LEFT JOIN tblOrderDiscount od ON o.OrderId=od.OrderId)
WHERE 
o.BusinessDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
AND o.IdNoLocation <> 'X'
GROUP BY o.IdNoLocation
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: An inflated `SUM()` due to a `JOIN` indicates your criteria is insufficient to match rows between tables 1:1.  Can an `o.OrderID` have multiple entries in `tblOrderDiscount`?

Comment: Yes, an Order (o.OrderID) can have more than one Discount applied (from TblOrderDiscount).

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result when there is more than one related row in either `tblOrderSurcharge` or `tblOrderDiscount`... you've got an implicit semi-cross join between the rows from those two tables.

There's a couple of approaches to "fixing" this, if you need the totals returned in a single statement.

One option is to use inline views to perform the totals, and then combine the rows. Essentially, run separate queries to get the totals from each table, and then combine the results on a unique key. For example:

```
SELECT o.IdNoLocation
     , o.Frequency
     , ISNULL(o.Spend, 0)       AS Spend
     , ISNULL(s.Surcharges), 0) AS Surcharges
     , ISNULL(s.Discounts), 0)  AS Discounts
  FROM ( SELECT ooo.IdNoLocation
              , COUNT(DISTINCT ooo.EncodedId) AS Frequency
              , SUM(ooo.Subtotal) AS Spend
           FROM tblOrder ooo
          WHERE ooo.BusinessDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
            AND ooo.IdNoLocation <> 'X'
         GROUP BY ooo.IdNoLocation
       ) o
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT oso.IdNoLocation
              , SUM(oss.Amount) AS Surcharges
           FROM tblOrderSurcharge oss
           JOIN tblOrder oso
             ON oso.OrderId = oss.OrderId
          WHERE oso.BusinessDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
            AND oso.IdNoLocation <> 'X'
          GROUP BY oso.IdNoLocation
       ) s
    ON s.IdNoLocation = o.IdNoLocation
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT odo.IdNoLocation
              , SUM(odd.Amount) AS Discounts
           FROM tblOrderDiscount odd
           JOIN tblOrder odo
             ON odo.OrderId = odd.OrderId
          WHERE odo.BusinessDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
            AND odo.IdNoLocation <> 'X'
          GROUP BY odo.IdNoLocation
       ) d
    ON d.IdNoLocation = o.IdNoLocation
```

(This isn't tested, just desk checked. Run each of the inline view queries (o, s, d) and verify the results from each of those queries is as you expect. Then, run the entire query, to combine the rows... in the outer query, we'll do the "outer" joins and deal with the "missing" rows and replacing NULLs with zeros)

Another option is to use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

To see why this doesn't work, run this query:

```
SELECT o.IdNoLocation,
o.EncodedId AS "Frequency", 
o.Subtotal AS "Spend", 
os.Amount AS "Surcharges",
od.Amount AS "Discounts" 
FROM ((tblOrder o
LEFT JOIN tblOrderSurcharge os ON o.OrderId=os.OrderId) 
LEFT JOIN tblOrderDiscount od ON o.OrderId=od.OrderId)
WHERE 
o.BusinessDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
AND o.IdNoLocation <> 'X'
```

The 'correct' answer is to use one table for both surcharges and discounts. I would assume that's no longer an option, but you can fake it with a view that performs a UNION ALL between the two tables.